# Three Column Grid responsive

Tags: css, html, layout, grid

I am a beginner to HTML and CSS. i have some knowledge of javascript, not jquery and also responsive design.

So I want to make a 3 column grid aligned to center and each with 33.33% width. Also a little space between each horizontally and some space on either side. but i can seem to align it to the center.
here is my html. I also want it to be Responsive. It should be reduced to two columns then to one and stuff like that. How could i achieve this?

Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Home.css" type="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="layout" align="center">
<div class="success"> </div>
<div class="success"> </div>
<div class="success"> </div>
<div class="success"> </div>
<div class="success"> </div>
<div class="success"> </div>
<div class="success"> </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.success {
display:inline-block;
background: tomato;
padding: 5px;
width: 200px;
height: 150px;
margin-top: 10px;
line-height: 150px;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 3em;
text-align: center
}

.success li:last-child {
float: none;
width: auto;
}

.layout {
width:75%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to start again.

Basically your html structure needs to reflect your 3 column layout. Usually this is achieved with `<div>` tags.

so something like:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="contentleft">
    your first column  content is here
  </div>
  <div id="contentcenter">
    the stuff for the middle goes here
  </div>
  <div id="contentright">
     etc. etc. etc.<br>
     ...
  </div>
</div>
```

then your .css can do something along the following lines:

```
#content {
   width: 900px;
}
#contentLeft {
   width:33%;
   float:left;
}
#contentcenter {
   width:33%;
   padding:1%;
   float:left;
}
#contentright {
   width: 33%;
   float:right;
}
```

Comment: For now, i want it to be 6 colored boxes, 3 columns, 2 rows, and spaces between them and the content div to be aligned to center. I did add background-color tag, but it didnt seem to work. and they are all like this

your first column content is here
the stuff for the middle goes here
etc. etc. etc.
...

This was the entire webpage.

Comment: I really want to figure this out. This should be three colored boxes horizontally with spacing between them and two boxes under the three boxes. So a grid with 3 columns and two rows aligned to the cnter of the page. I could not make the three by two grid. Your answer includes all text and is not what i wanted. Could You maybe Make what i asked.
thanks, all help is greatly appreciated and noted, :D

Comment: try this page http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201012/how_to_create_a_3-column_layout_with_css/